# How can I make a graph with vertical exaggeration?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to make a graph with vertical exaggeration?

I am trying to plot several graphs (normalized), but in the Y scale I only can see some little bumps.

Comment: Your question is not very clear in what you see right now and what you expect (which results in answers that don't fit with your expectation, as you already noticed). Could you provide a sample of your data or a picture of what you have right now?

Answer (score 1):

Manually set the y-axis limits in the graph properties dialog.

Comment: I tried your recommendation, but t didnt work, my graphs are totally flat. I am trying to plot several graphs (normalized), but in the Y scale I only can see some little bumps.

Comment: This should work, in Excel 2003, right-click on the Y-axis, select `Format Axis...`, click on the `Scale` tab, set the minumum and maximum to the min and max Y values for your data.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes extreme values will make the rest of the data look like very small bumps in a graph.  Remove these values, which sometimes are categorized as outliers, and re-plot everything, this should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties dialog for the y-axis and select Logarithmic.

Comment: This does not exaggerate, it un-exaggerates.

Comment: @nnewton, yes I agree but the question is pretty vague. If the OP's data is mainly small values with a few very large values then Excel's auto-scaling will make the small values fairly indistinguishable from each other ("little bumps"). Logarithmic mode will help spread them out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply adjust the graph with your mouse as in clicking and dragging one of the corner points of the graph to be taller and thus look vertically exaggerated?

Comment: Compared to the other suggestions, this would be very uncontrolled and difficult to reverse.